# Android Retrofit 2 make POST request multiple params (without FormUrlEncoded)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I would like to make a POST request call with multiple params instead of one @Body param. I'm not using @FormUrlEncoded annotation on this one and I don't want to. I'm using Retrofit 2.0.

Currently, the call is made this way :

```
@POST("user/register")
Call<APIResponse> register(@Body RequestRegisterParams params);
```

with RequestRegisterParams being :

```
public class RequestRegisterParams {
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

I would like to be able to do this (with proper annotations of course) :

```
@POST("user/register")
Call<APIResponse> register(String username, String email, String password);
```

My goal is to get rid of the data model class. Is there a way to do this or a POST request without @FormUrlEncoded must have only one @Body param ? I know it can only be one @Body param but maybe with other annotations ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/register")
Call<APIResponse> updateUser(@Field("username") String username, @Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

**@Field** is Named pair for a form-encoded request.

Comment: @Shade Issac. Do let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanted to know if it was possible without the @FormUrlEncoded annotation